# Вёрстка hexagon

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Прошу помощи у более опытных ребят. Учусь только 3 месяца, взял себе второй макет для учебы и там вот такая секция:

[image]

Как её можно сверстать, проблема в том, что на соте разные бордеры?
Плюс, как это грамотно отпозиционировать не статично?
Помогите пожалуйста, всю голову сломал уже.

Comment: Вы вообще не знаете как подобный блок(и) сверстать, или же вы что-то делали, есть какие-то наработки?

Comment: Уважаемый, как же Вы не можете понять, что задача для того и даётся, чтобы ломать голову. Учитывая, что это тестовое задание на одном из курсов, данный макет разбирался сотни раз. Да, он даже на ЮТубе есть - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cibmycvhUs К тому же, Вы не привели ни строчки своих попыток.

Comment: https://github.com/Hleb-Rastsisheusky/Rastsisheusky_hometasks/tree/master/diplom

Comment: Вот что у меня имеется на данный момент.
Я понимаю как сверстать шестигранник. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как спозиционировать их грамотно, поэтому и обратился за помощью. Это не значит, что я впустую скопирую код и все. Я хочу разобраться. И мне в этом нужна помощь.
На ютубе я видел это метод...но мне кажется это далеко не лучшее решение. Поэтому обратился сюда.

Comment: Тогда ваш вопрос не совсем корректен, его нужно дополнить. В GitHub сомнительно что кто-то будет рыться, тем более что пример воспроизвести там не получится. Сделайте пример, в котором воспроизведите проблему и желательно чтоб это было видно на данном ресурсе. Тут есть такая техническая возможность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 блок, для наглядности, если вы не понимаете как:

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 173.21px;
  background-color: #84ac9b;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  border-left: solid 1px #333333;
  border-right: solid 1px #333333;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 212.13px;
  height: 212.13px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 42.9340px;
}

.hexagon:before {
  top: -106.0660px;
  border-top: solid 1.4142px #333333;
  border-right: solid 1.4142px #333333;
}

.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -106.0660px;
  border-bottom: solid 1.4142px #333333;
  border-left: solid 1.4142px #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

[Вот тут](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) уже есть реализованные, все основные геометрические фигуры.

Comment: Как связать блоки подобно вашему макету вам любезно предоставили в ссылке на видео. Посмотрели ->  набрали -> готово!

Comment: Спасибо вам! Скажите, вашу доброту на этом сайте нужно как-то оценить? Может голоса, оценки какие-то...извиняюсь если ответ глупый. Я просто новый раз на этом сайте.

Comment: @L.F.C. Наверное я тоже добавлю ответ (+), но SVG

Comment: @Alexandr_TT автор создал ещё один вопрос, с уточнением, глянь туда. Этот придется переоткрывать, если добавить что-то захочешь. Я если честно, думал что ты его видел, подумал тебе не интересен данный вопрос.

Comment: @L.F.C. я видел. Я только за, когда отвечают. Чем больше ответов, тем лучше :)