# Требуется помощь с SVG - шестигранный шестиугольник(?)

Tags: html, css, svg

Нужно сверстать подобный блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что тут требуется SVG, но пока по быстрому сверстал эти элементы в лоб (элементы начинаются с "Сухие строительные смеси" и по часовой стрелке):

```css
div.data {
  height: 720px;
  padding-top: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  width: 550px;
  height: 530px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
ul li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
}
ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("/images/bg/bg-about-item.png") no-repeat center center;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul li a:hover::before {
  background: url("/images/bg/bg-about-item-hover.png") no-repeat center center;
}
ul li a span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  right: 92px;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 157px;
  right: 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 92px;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 94px;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  top: 155px;
  left: 4px;
}
ul li:nth-child(6) {
  top: 0;
  left: 94px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <img src="/images/content/cat01.png" alt="" />
   <a href="#!">
    <span>Сухие строительные смеси</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="/images/content/cat02.png" alt="" />
   <a href="#!">
    <span>Тротуарная плитка из бетона</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="/images/content/cat03.png" alt="" />
   <a href="#!">
    <span>Тротуарная плитка из резины</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="/images/content/cat04.png" alt="" />
   <a href="#!">
    <span>Металлоконструкции</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="/images/content/cat05.png" alt="" />
   <a href="#!">
    <span>Облицовочный кирпич</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="/images/content/cat06.png" alt="" />
   <a href="#!">
    <span>Теплоблок</span>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Запускать бессмысленно, картинок нет) Но если нужно будет, добавлю.

У каждого блока сейчас на внешнем слое эффект затемнения в виде полупрозрачной png-картинки, которая сменяется при наведении на полупрозрачную желтую.

А теперь собственно вопросы: как такое сверстать на SVG с заполнением каждой фигуры картинкой и текстом (никакой статики, все меняется через админку), будет ли у таких фигур работать псевдоэлемент `::before` (по идее должен), а еще по центру влепить картинку отдельным элементом (сейчас там логотип, абсолютноспозиционированный относительно родителя, не показываю, ибо клиенты)?

**P.S.** SVG сам не рисую(( Пробовал копировать примеры, но как управлять координатами точек, не понимаю, сетки в голове нет, а уж как впихивать туда текст, подавно.

**P.S.S.** Можно просто пнуть в верном направлении, например, как рисовать 6-угольники при заданных размерах вьюбокса.

**P.S.S.S.** Буду рад, если на вопрос заглянет **Alexandr_TT** ;)

Comment: сегодня достаточно поздно, а давать ответ в торопях, кое-как не хочу. Давайте завтра. Хорошо бы авторские картинки получить, чтобы было один в один. За хороший вопрос плюс!

Comment: Забыл добавить! В этим ячейках еще и ссылки должны быть.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да картинки любые, главное чтобы квадратные и вылезали за контур шестигранника, который их, по сути "продавит" через себя.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/948865/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/948884/262779

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Работаем в любом векторном редакторе, я использую Inkscape 
Процесс рисования не показываю но поясню что в редакторе надо выбрать форму ромбика который будет закрашивать белым цветом fill:white; или на hex: fill:#fff и будем дублировать ...
Будем делать обтравочные маски т.е в SVG это clip-path дабы не плодить кучу pattern ..

1) Рисуем ромб

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Заливаем его белым цветом

3) импортируем картинку по одной

4) и делаем обтравочный контур

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5) так поступаем со всеми изображениями и расставляем нужным способом

6) рисуем опять такие же ромбы и накладываем их выше если вдруг они будут при перемещении 
залазить вниз то воспользуемся этим шорткатом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее сохряняем как `Обычный SVG` и открываем в любимом текстовом редакторе, я воспользуюсь Notepad++ и присваиваем всем повторяющимся элементам class а не нужное удаляем, к примеру у image есть id и этим class в defs создаём style и пишем те стили которые продублированные ...

Продублированным ромбам с уже созданным class придаём обычные css свойства т.е opacity и при hover показываем и меняем уже нужные стили в css

На выходе имеем SVG который меньше исходного

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1400 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1088">
   <path d="m-173 116 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" style="fill:#5599ff;stroke-width:.8;stroke:#000000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1105">
   <path d="m-393 212 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:.8;stroke:#000000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1137">
   <path d="m-523 154 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" style="fill:#f9f9f9;stroke-width:.8;stroke:#000000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1154">
   <path d="m-687 161 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:.8;stroke:#000000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1175">
   <path d="m-658 254 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:.8;stroke:#000000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1192">
   <path d="m-966 116 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:.8;stroke:#000000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <style>
    .g{
    opacity:0;
    transition:0.34s;
 }
 .g:hover{
   opacity:1;
 }
     .diamont{
    fill:#00ffff;
    stroke-width:1px;
    stroke:#000000;

  }
  .image{
   image-rendering:optimizeQuality;
  }
  .path{
   fill:#000000;
   stroke-width:1;
   stroke:#000000
  }
  text{
    fill:#fff;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:25px;
    stroke-width:.3;
  }
  .parent{
    transform:translateY(10px)translateX(2px);
  }
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(435 178)">
  <image class="image" transform="translate(42 -119)" x="-223" y="-63" width="318" height="270" clip-path="url(#clipPath1088)" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cSY6.jpg"/>
  <image class="image" transform="translate(55 129)" x="-414" y="31" width="334" height="267" clip-path="url(#clipPath1105)" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3tjh.jpg"/>
  <image class="image" transform="translate(386 191)" x="-542" y="-31" width="397" height="265" clip-path="url(#clipPath1137)" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aork7.jpg"/>
  <image class="image" transform="translate(355 -168)" x="-692" y="-8" width="213" height="231" clip-path="url(#clipPath1154)" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dFKn.jpg"/>
  <image class="image" transform="translate(223 -88)" x="-654" y="81" width="324" height="235" clip-path="url(#clipPath1175)" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwmVV.jpg"/>
  <image class="image" transform="translate(932 57)" x="-974" y="-62" width="418" height="252" clip-path="url(#clipPath1192)"  preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Wb3.jpg"/>
  
 <g class="parent">
  <g class="g" transform="translate(-2 -9)">
   <path  class="diamont" d="m-331-6 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" />
    <a xlink:href=""><text x="-278.10455" y="-50.342541">текст 1</text></a>
 </g>
  <g class="g" transform="translate(-2 -9)">
   <path  class="diamont" d="m-131-3 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z"/>
    <a xlink:href=""><text x="-84.960121" y="-50.342541" >текст 2</text></a>
  </g>

  <g class="g" transform="translate(-2 -9)">
   <path  class="diamont" d="m-34 173 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" />
    <a xlink:href=""><text x="13.313688" y="131.08603">текст 3</text></a>
  </g>

  <g class="g" transform="translate(-2 -9)">
   <path  class="diamont" d="m-138 345 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" />
    <a xlink:href=""><text x="-91.007744" y="303.44318" >текст 4</text></a>
  </g>

  <g class="g" transform="translate(-2 -9)">
   <path  class="diamont" d="m-338 341 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" />
    <a xlink:href=""><text x="-286.04346" y="306.46698">текст 5</text></a>
  </g>

  <g class="g" transform="translate(-2 -9)">
   <path  class="diamont" d="m-435 165 2-116 101-56 99 60-2 116-101 56z" />
   <a xlink:href=""><text x="-383.41162" y="113.32209">текст 6</text></a>
  </g>
  </g>

 </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91187/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-maximlensky).

Comment: @DaemonHK хороший, добротный ответ (+) Более подробно см. в чате

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь подробный ответ и пищу для ума)

Comment: и все таки это не ромбы =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну да...это не ромбы ...это шестигранники  ..

Answer (score 6):

Вот, соорудил на d3.js

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<svg width=300 height=300></svg>
<script>
var size = 250, r = 40, k = 1.9;

var images = [
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7GyM.jpg',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9Md.png',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFeUb.png',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hw3.png',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqZZR.png',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWKHf.png'
];
  
var hexbin = d3.hexbin();

var svg = d3.select('svg')
            .attr('viewBox', `${-size/2} ${-size/2} ${size} ${size}`);
  
svg.append('defs')
   .selectAll("path")
   .data(images)
   .enter()
     .append('pattern')
     .attr('width', 100)
     .attr('height', 100)
     .attr('id', (d, i) => `img${i}`)
     .append('image')
     .attr('width', 100)
     .attr('height', 100)
     .attr('xlink:xlink:href', d => d)
  
svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(coords(images))
   .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("stroke", 'black')
     .attr("fill", (d, i) => `url(#img${i})`)
     .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d[0]*r*k}, ${d[1]*r*k})`)
     .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon(r));

function coords(arr) {
  return arr.map((d, i) => i * Math.PI/3 + Math.PI/6)
            .map(i => [Math.sin(i), Math.cos(i)])
}
</script>
```

Comment: везде успеваешь! :) (+)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Но, боюсь, библиотеки не подойдут(

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я про js в целом) политика компании такая

Comment: @DaemonHK а в чем вопрос тогда, как нарисовать 6 гексагонов? stackoverflow все-аки ресурс по программированию..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну, не только)

Comment: @DaemonHK в общем я очень скептически отношусь к ручной верстке, т.к. я программист =), представьте что завтра вам скажут нарисовать гексагоны побольше или их надо будет 14

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91194/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-stranger-in-the-q).